# Repeating/looping javascript function to check if a cookie has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, cookies, repeat

I am trying to make a script that will repeat every 5 seconds.

The script that will be repeated will check to see if a cookie exists.
If the cookie does not exist, the page is redirected.
If the cookie does exist, nothing happens.

The cookies are working fine, my only problem is that it doesn't repeat!

I am using jQuery to identify/check the cookie and that is working fine.

I would like to know what is wrong with the code please.

I have looked online many times, but have had no luck in finding what I need.
This is the cookie plugin I use: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
var checkcookie = $.cookie('myCookie');

checklogin();
function checklogin(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(checkcookie == null){
            //if cookie not set
            window.location.href='/';
        }
        else{
            //if cookie set
        }

    }, 5000);

checklogin();//to recall the script after it is done
}
```

Or if any one has an alternative method of checking whether a cookie has changed, I would love to know!

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine, but your cookie value not changing - it set once and forever. Try to include it in your `setTimeout()`:

```
checklogin();

function checklogin(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var checkcookie = $.cookie('myCookie');

        if(checkcookie == null){
            window.location.href='/';
        }
        else{
            //if cookie set
        }

    }, 5000);

    checklogin(); //to recall the script after it is done
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I combined both yours and Andy's and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it that way the checklogin call has to be inside the setTimeout function otherwise it's called immediately everytime.

Also i'd use a setInterval instead, so you don't need you recursive function:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(checkcookie == null){
        window.location.href='/';
    }else{
        //if cookie set
    }
},5000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I combined both yours and Zoltan's and it works great!